# JS script event WASD to show index of a table

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello I'm new to JS and I have a school project I have a problem with. So basically I have to make an array where 0 will be a path and 1 will be a wall that I can't select. I've got an array already going based on values you can randomly input on the website and I have to make key event that will check if the index of and array value is 0 or 1 and will display the index that I moved to (if it's possible).

I don't know how to implement specific key event. For example, pressing <kbd>W</kbd> should move me for example 10 positions up if `var width = 10`, <kbd>D</kbd> will move me +1, <kbd>S</kbd> will move me 10 indexes up and <kbd>A</kbd> will move me 1 index backwards. I can make it only in JS not jQuery becouse we haven`t learned it yet.

Comment: Can you provide the code that you have thus far?

Comment: Well you implement the listeners like any other, filter the keypress and the rest is up to your program logic, which in fact is your task for your school project. the syntax for listeners is `window.addEventListener('event', fnHandler);`. In your case listeners would probably be `keydown` or `keypress`. Welcome to SO. If you can use arrow keys instead of W, A , S, D you can take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, each key has a particular code. Here is some programming that uses for the arrow keys:
'''
function checkKey (e) {
e = window.event;

```
      if (e.keyCode == '38') {
          //down
      }
      else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
          //up
      }
      else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
          //left
      }
      else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
          //right             
      }
   };
```

The keyCode refers to the particular code of each input. You can adapt these to WASD with the following number codes:

W:87
A:65
S:83
D:68

Replace the arrow code with the WASD code, and you should be fine.